# How to use Promise to add up multiple value?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I want to read the three txt files, and add up the text results return from realFile(), below is my code used callback. How do we use Promise and .then() to add up all text?

```
fs.readFile('./a.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
   if(err) console.log(err)
   fs.readFile('./b.txt', 'utf8', (err, newData) => {
     if(err) console.log(err)
     fs.readFile('./c.txt', 'utf8',(err, newestData) => {
       if (err) console.log(err)
       console.log(data+newData+newestData)
     })
   })
})
```

Comment: Node provides a promise-based version of the `fs` module; use that along with `Promise.all`

Comment: Do you want to stop on error, or continue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fs.promises` API to obtain promisified methods.

Then, just do a `Promise.all`:

```js
const p1 = fs.promises.readFile('./a.txt', 'utf8')
const p2 = fs.promises.readFile('./b.txt', 'utf8')
const p3 = fs.promises.readFile('./c.txt', 'utf8')

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
  .then(([v1, v2, v3]) => console.log(v1 + v2 + v3))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

You can also avoid repetition with arrays:

```js
const files = ['./a.txt', './b.txt', './c.txt']

Promise.all(
  files.map(file => fs.promises.readFile(file, 'utf8'))
)
  .then(([v1, v2, v3]) => console.log(v1 + v2 + v3))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

If you are really looking for  something with multiple `.then()`s in it, you could do it this way (though it's not much better than your original callback thing):

```js
fs.promises.readFile('./a.txt', 'utf8').then(v1 => 
  fs.promises.readFile('./b.txt', 'utf8').then(v2 => 
    fs.promises.readFile('./c.txt', 'utf8').then(v3 => 
      console.log(v1+v2+v3)
    )
  )
)
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: I want to show the .then() chain to implement it, is there have a way to use three times .then()?

Comment: Why would you want to? What else do you want to achieve with that, that doesn't work this way?

Comment: @LeeAlex `p1.then(file1Data => p2.then(file2Data => [file1Data, file2Data])).then(arr => p3.then(file3Data => [...arr, file3Data])).then(dataArr => { ... }).catch(...)`

Comment: @FZs It works, but I just wanna see how to only using .than() to compare using callback

Comment: @LeeAlex I added a solution using only `.then()`s, but the real power of promises is their composability, so you should compare your code with the other solutions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code snippet below I have added logic for both promises and async/await

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const util = require("util");

    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

    // return promise which can resolved later
    // data is array of promise in same order of 
    let data = Promise.all([
        readFile('file.txt', 'utf8'),
        readFile('file.txt', 'utf8'),
        readFile('file.txt', 'utf8')
    ])

    data.then(([data1, data2, data3]) => {
        console.log(data1, data2, data3)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

We can achieve this using async/await with even simple syntax

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data1 = await readFile('file.txt', 'utf8');
        const data2 = await readFile('file.txt', 'utf8');
        const data3 = await readFile('file.txt', 'utf8');
        console.log(data1, data2, data3);
    }

    fetchData();
```